# YUI get element by id method not working for numeric starting ids

Tags: javascript, yui

I've just switched from YUI2 to YUI3. So, instead of using `YAHOO.util.Dom.get(ID_OF_ELEMENT)`, I tried to use `Y.one('#ID_OF_ELEMENT)'`. It works fine for a *div* with *id* **img123**, but not with **123img** or **123**.

I tried also using `Y.all` but it didn't work. The only way I found to make it work, while still using YUI, was using `Y.DOM.byId` (shown as an [alternative in YUI forum](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7346)).

So what I did was to grab the element with the last and get the *Node* with first, like this:

```
Y.one(Y.DOM.byId(ID_OF_ELEMENT)).append(SOME_HTML_CONTENT);
```

I could not alone using only `Y.DOM.byId` because I needed to manipulate it's content as a *Node*.

So, is there a way to do that using only `Y.one`? **Is that a YUI bug?**

I have made a comment on that [YUI forum entry](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=2169), since I don't know if that's really a bug I could fill in [YUI bug reporting tool](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/report).

Answer (score 8):

If you use html4:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Also see [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2).

=== UPDATE ===

For html5:

In your example using `Y.one(...)` yui calls the browsers native query selector: `querySelector(selector)` (see [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/dom_js_selector-native.js.html#l169)).
But not all browsers querySelector function accept all allowed html5 `id`s. E.g. the firfox10 native query selector fails for `id`s with starting digit (try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BnTvH/) in different browsers).
Why? Mozilla uses CSS2.1 specification for selectors:
Mozilla [links in his querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.querySelector#Specification) to the Selectors API Level 1.
In the [first chapter "Abstract"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#abstract):

> > Selectors, which are widely used in CSS, are patterns that match against elements in a tree structure [[SELECT]](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#SELECT)[CSS21].

The [[SELECT]](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#SELECT) links to the [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/) and there in [chapter 6.5 "ID selectors"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#id-selectors):

> > ...
> >     An ID selector contains a "number sign" (U+0023, #) immediately followed by the ID value, which must be an [CSS identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).
> >     ...

From the linked [css2.1 identifiers specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> > In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

=== UPDATE ===

You can use following selector `[id="123"]`. E.g.:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    Y.one('[id="123"]').on("click", function (e) {
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PtT55/).

Comment: That's HTML4, not HTML5. Element IDs can start with numbers or be completely numeric in HTML5. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Well, that explains things. So, I guess YUI3 should support HTML5 spec. 
This is really a matter because a lot of websites can be using numeric-only or numeric-starting ids. On this specific one I'm dealing with, I can't control that fact. And using that kind of hack is quite ugly.

Comment: I've added an alternate selector.

Comment: @scessor Thanks for your help. I think the explanation was deep and good enough. Also, the last example shows a good way to circumvent that problem, at least in a better way than selecting by DOM id an then using the Y.one selector, which is the way I'm doing now.

Comment: using it this way [id="123"] works. I've tested it on YUI 2.9.